# No Internet connection on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking, windows-8, connection

I just installed Ubuntu on my laptop Lenovo Ideapad Z510, and no Wi-Fi connection is found by ubuntu. I tried to find a solution, but I didn't solve my problem.

Can someone please help me?
Thank you

Comment: Try pressing the [Fn] key and [F7] key together, which toggles the WiFi Airplane mode on this model.

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless device from the terminal command: lspci -nn | grep 0280 Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Lenovo laptops are probably the most linux friendly made, but that doesn't mean that drivers for every wireless card they may have are necessarily included with every distro.

In the entirety of my 50+ ubuntu (not really counting) installations, those made while not connected to the internet were prone to problems related to missing drivers.  However, you can overcome this issue by following the steps outlined below:

1. Connect your laptop to the internet using an Ethernet cable.
2. Open the update manager (go to the HUD and type UP).
3. EVEN if it claims nothing is need of updating, click CHECK.
4. After it acknowledges that it is in need of updates, click "Install Updates".
5. When the updates have completed, shut down your laptop, disconnect the Ethernet cable and reboot.  Your WiFi device should be recognized.

If your WiFi device is not recognized, that suggests that it is so new (or so peculiar) that you may need to use a tool such as "System Profiler & benchmark" to identify its chipset and then use the Synaptic Package Manager to install particular drivers to make it work.  However being you have a Lenovo, I think that's particularly unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the Network applet icon in your system tray?  Is it there and disabled or just missing?

From my previous experience, on my dual boot machine, I had the Wifi disabled in Windows and when I booted into Fedora, Wifi was disabled too.  The tooltip said "Disabled by a hardware switch".  However, I had not disabled it while in Fedora.  So, I booted back into Windows and enabled the Wifi and rebooted back to Fedora and it was on (detected).

Not saying, you have this exact same situation but I anyway mentioned - doesn't hurt to check and try.  Let us know.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help thus far. I managed to connect directly to my adsl router wifi. Ran updates. Rebooted. Still doesn't want to connect to my Apple wifi network which connects to my router via AirPort Extreme? Sees the Apple network, password for the Apple wifi network correct...